# Vueify + Elixir + Hotloading - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I've set up Elixir to use Vueify with hot reload plugin. Everything compiles ok but I get a console error on my compiled file and the Vue component doesn't appear to be transforming to html, it still shows the `<app></app>` tags. If I remove the hot reload plugin from elixir, the page renders fine.

The error is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

The console output it

```
[HMR] Attempting websocket connection to http://localhost:3123
app.js:10904 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
[vue-devtools] Ready. Detected Vue v1.0.26
[HMR] Websocket connection successful.
[HMR] Updated modules ["resources/assets/js/embeds/html/app.vue"]
```

So it's worth mentioning that it is receiving messages from hot reloading, it just doesn't render the page because of this error. The error is happening on the following lines in the compiled `app.js` file.

```
// compat with < 2.0.0-alpha.7
  if (Vue.config._lifecycleHooks.indexOf('init') > -1) {
    initHookName = 'init'
  }
```

Here are my files

**gulpfile.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

if (gutil.env._.indexOf('watch') > -1) {
    //  Add the browserify HMR plugin
    elixir.config.js.browserify.plugins.push({
        name: 'browserify-hmr',
        options: {}
    })
}

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.browserify('embeds/html/main.js', 'public/js/embeds/html/app.js');
});
```

**main.js**

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var App = require('./app.vue')

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        app: App
    },
    created: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<style>

</style>

<template>
    <div id="player-wrapper">
        {{ msg }}
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                msg: 'Hello world!'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <app></app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be a version compatibility problem, between Vue, and Vue-hot-reload-api.

As an example, vueify@8.7.0 currently depends on vue-hot-reload-api@1.3.2, which only seems to be compatible with Vue@1.x.

From personal experience, this specific error occurred to me, when using vue-hot-reload-api@2.x with vue@1.x, although i have not tested it the other way around.

A note a the very top of [Vue-hot-reload-api's Github readme](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hot-reload-api#vue-hot-reload-api), also seems to verify this problem.

In my case, i just reinstalled the vue@1.0.26-compatible version of vue-hot-reload-api, as following:

```
npm install --save-dev vue-hot-reload-api@^1.3.2
```

So have a look at the versions of your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I downgraded to vue-hot-reload-api@1.3.2 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, older vue-hot-reload-api worked for me as well!